# TcpListener Timeout/about/something? Without ASync?

Tags: .net, sockets, multithreading, tcplistener

I create a thread which uses TcpListener and when my app closes i'd like the thead to terminate. I can call abort but the thread is still alive since TcpListener is blocking with AcceptTcpClient.

Is it possible to about or set a timeout or to do SOMETHING with AcceptTcpClient? i cant imagine how it would be useful if theres no way to stop it from blocking forever. My code is serial and i would like it to stay that way so is there a solution without using BeginAcceptTcpClient? and writing ASync code?

Comment: Yet another reason why blocking socket code should never be put into production. Asynchronous socket communications is the only 100% reliable way to do things.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple solution. CHECK with pending.

```
while(!server.Pending())
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
```

Comment: How is this correct? this is not a time out. This is a blocking state which will proceed only if a client is connected. server.AcceptTcpClient() will also wait for client to connect. If no client is connected, it will remain in wait loop

Comment: @Sid133 - This code may block, but you don't have a block after it checks if pending connections exist. You could run its own thread to do all of this and create your own timeout mechanism. For example you could use an integer, which increments each time it goes into Thread.Sleep. Once it reaches 'n', leave the loop, have the TcpClient being 'null', and end the method in a failed state (for example an exception).

Answer (score 4):

You could replace the call to AcceptTcpClient with one for Socket.Select(), which can timeout.

```
var sockl = new ArrayList { listener.Server };
Socket.Select(sockl, null, null, _timeout_);
if (sockl.Contains(listener.Server)) listener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

Answer (score 4):

I use `AcceptTcpClient()` in a `while(!Disposing)` loop to accept my clients.
When I dispose the Class I call the `Stop()` function of the `TcpListener` and set `Disposing` to true; like this:

```
public class Server : IDisposable
{
    private TcpListener _tcpListener;
    private bool _isDisposing;

    public void Start()
    {
        (new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients))).Start();
    }

    private void ListenForClients()
    {
        this._tcpListener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, this.ListenPort);
        this._tcpListener.Start();

        while (!_isDisposing)
        {
            //blocks until a client has connected to the server
            TcpClient client = this._tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

            if (client == null) continue;

            //create a thread to handle communication with connected client
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this._isDisposing = true;
        this._tcpListener.Stop();
    }
}
```

Note that this is just a small excerpt from a server class...

This way, the program can stay locked on the `AcceptTcpClient()` function and still be ended.
However, the listening itself must also happen on a separate `Thread (Start() function)`.